# How to parse json data correctly using jq to set to var inside shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, jq

I have like this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

JSON_DATA=$(echo $INPUT_DATA | base64 --decode)

echo "JSON:" $JSON_DATA # Result: {"id":546,"sha":"fh456h8"}
 
RP_SHA=$( jq -re  '.sha' <<< $JSON_DATA)
RP_ID=$(jq -re .id <<< $JSON_DATA)
```

I tried parse like this method but this method return error with message:

> syntax error: unexpected redirection

Also tried parse like this:

```
RP_SHA=\$( jq -re  '.sha' <<< \$JSON_DATA)
```

This method return error with message:

> syntax error: unexpected "("

How I can correctly parse and set to my var json data using `jq` in my case?

Comment: Your script is running with `sh` POSIX shell, which does not support here-strings (`<<<`)

Comment: Then what I must use instead of `<<<` ? @Inian

Comment: `RP_SHA=$( printf '%s' "$JSON_DATA" | jq -re  '.sha' )` and double quote all your shell variables